# Area of part $S$ of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ that lies inside the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = ax$

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals

By symmetry, I can calculate as $$2\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{a\cos\theta} \frac a{\sqrt{a^2-r^2}} r\,dr\,d\theta= a^2(\pi-2)$$

but when I calculate as $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{a\cos\theta} \frac a{\sqrt{a^2-r^2}} r\,dr\,d\theta= a^2\pi$$

I thought the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ consider as even function, both of them should get same result, thus, I don't know why the second solution is wrong.

Comment: Here is a closely related one: [Surface area of sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$ cut by cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = ay$, $a>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/867961/)

Comment: I believe you've used something like $\sqrt{a^2-a^2\cos^2 \theta}=a\sin \theta$ for second integral, which is not correct.